# (Rails app deployment) capistrano bundles with invalid ruby version

Tags: ruby, rvm, capistrano, bundler, rvm-capistrano

I have Digital Ocean ubuntu droplet, I have installed RVM and set ruby version to 2.1.1

On server:

```
> env
RUBY_VERSION=ruby-2.1.1
```

`ruby -v` in my project: `ruby 2.1.1p76 (2014-02-24 revision 45161) [x86_64-darwin12.0]`

I've tried to deploy app with capistrano, but it failed, because of `bundler`

command `cap production deploy` creates
`/home/deploy/app_name/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0`

Where can I set a valid bundle ruby version? Why `cap production deploy` creates 2.3.0 v. directory?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this can happen because you have system-wide ruby 2.3.0, and capistrano uses it by default.

You can give a try to https://github.com/capistrano/rvm or some related, more up to date gem, that provides rvm integration with capistrano.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and it was like Stanislav said, it's a problem with the rvm system-wide installation. I'm sure that you have installed the Ruby on Rails One click Application. In order to solve it I created a new clean Ubuntu Droplet, and installed rvm single-user manually.